# What does this regular expression mean - '(?<word'?

Tags: regex, perl

I found this regular expression in [Raisin](http://search.cpan.org/~rtkh/Raisin-0.72/lib/Raisin.pm) code:

```
my ($a, $b, $r) = ("(?<$token>", ')', undef);
```

In this case $token is some word (param name). This code used in functon for creating regular expression. Sample result for `/users/:id` is:

```
/users/(?<id>[^/]+?)(?:\.[^.]+?)?
```

I dont understand what does its mean: `(?<id>` ?

I know positive and negative look-behind - `(?<=` and `(?<!`. But i don`t know this.

Comment: [named captures](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)

Comment: Where i can read about it?

Comment: just edited to add a link :)  Search for that term, "named captures".  See an example of use in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45528723/4653379), for instance

Comment: Oh, its from Perl 5.10. Thanks.